# Access Denied on Windows for AWS Credentials file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

No matter what I try it seems my web service cannot access my .aws/credentials file.

I always get this error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '{PATH}' is denied.

Here is what I have tried:

- Move the path from the default directory to the website root
- Change the website app pool to run as my user account
- Given `Everyone` full control of the folder and the file
- Verify that when I put the same key and secret into the web.config the call works
- Tried removing the region from the config
- Tried removing the path from the config

Here is my config (note if I don't provide the path, even when in the default location, it says no credentials file was found)

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="default" />
<add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1"/>
<add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="{PATH}" />
```

In the AWS toolkit I have a `default' profile setup as well that has rights but that does not help this work.

I have even tried the legancy format called out in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#creds-assign). What am I missing? It seems I have followed everything AWS calls out in their docs.

I am using Castle Windsor DI so could that be getting in the way?

```
container.Register(
            Component.For<IAmazonDynamoDB>()
                .ImplementedBy<AmazonDynamoDBClient>()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue<RegionEndpoint>(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IDynamoDBContext>()
                .ImplementedBy<DynamoDBContext>()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IAmazonDynamoDB, AmazonDynamoDBClient>())
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue<DynamoDBContextConfig>(
                    new DynamoDBContextConfig
                    {
                        TableNamePrefix = configurationManager.GetRequiredAppSetting<string>(Constants.Web.AppSettings.AwsDynamoDbPrefix),
                        Conversion = DynamoDBEntryConversion.V2
                    }))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you have is that the path `~\.aws\credentials` is only defined when logged in as a user.

A Windows services such as IIS is not logged in as the user that created the credentials file. Therefore the the path is not accessible to the Windows service. Actually the service does not know what user to look into. For example if your user name is john, the path would be `c:\users\john\.aws\credentials`. The Windows service does not know about your identity.

Note: I believe - but I am not 100% sure - is that a windows service will look in `c:\.aws` for credentials. I have used this path in the past but I cannot find Amazon reference documentation to support this. I no longer store credentials on my EC2 instances, so I am out of touch on the location `c:\.aws`.

You have a number of choices. Create the credentials as usual. Then create a directory outside of your IIS installation and setup such as `c:\.aws`. Copy `~\.aws` to `c:\.aws`. Then specify the full path in your programs.

A much better and more secure method, if you are running your services on AWS, is to use IAM Role. Create a role with the desired permissions and attach the role to your EC2 instance. All AWS SDKs and Tools know how to find the credentials from AWS Metadata.

There are many more methods such as EC2 Parameter Store. Storing credentials on your instances or inside your program is not a good idea.

[Edit after thinking more about the error message]

You may have an issue where IIS does not have access rights to the location where the credentials are stored.

Open Windows Explorer and locate the folder for your credentials file. Right click this folder, select Properties and click the Security tab. From here, choose Edit then Add. The following users must be added and given at least READ permissions: IUSR & IIS_IUSRS. You may need to add "LIST FOLDER CONTENTS".

Comment: Agreed on the IAM role for the server. On the server it will use IAM role. This however is local development. As I noted above I also have tried to move where the file is at "Move the path from the default directory to the website root". Since this is local Dev and I am logged in as me the path is define and IIS app pool is running as me it should have access to the path as well.

Comment: For a Windows server running on a local development machine, everything applies except your cannot use an IAM role. You still have to store your credentials in a location that the IIS service can access.

Comment: Agreed. My question here is why can't it access it even when the credentials file sits along side all the rest of the site files and IIS runs as me and/or when I have granted everyone rights to it?

Comment: What is the value for PATH in this line: <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="{PATH}" />

Comment: Does your credentials file have a profile name "default"? Also, try using an absolute value for path like this: <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="c:\.aws\credentials"/>

Comment: I have added another solution to the bottom of my answer. This provides a solution if IIS does not have rights to access the credentials file.

Comment: Note: Move your credentials out of the web server directory to a location outside of IIS. Then follow the permissions part that I added to my answer.

Comment: No joy. I moved the credentials file to C:\, added both users and gave them full control. Still get `access denied` error. I even tried giving `everyone` full control to the file, no change.

Comment: Do not assume that a Windows service is part of "everyone". You should specifically assign access permissions to Windows services. In your case something very simple is being overlooked.

Comment: Agreed. Hence I added IIS user and everyone. Agreed it is probably something simple just can't see what.

Comment: You need to add two IIS users:  IUSR and IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: Ya I added them both... Sorry should have said both before.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?